# Associating data from database to my object

Tags: c#, data-binding

I am a beginner when it comes to databases and c# (using them together) and I am trying to associate the values from a database to the attributes of a class.

I remember seing somewhere something like:

```
private attribute
[Data binding]
public Attribute
{
     get { return attribute; }
     set { attribute = value; }
}
```

What is it? What should I look to use something like this. I am using an ADO.NET EMD, but I'm not sure what to do next mainly because I am not sure what to look into.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably thinking of the [[Bindable]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.bindableattribute.aspx) attribute that can be placed on properties of a Control to tell Visual Studio to show the property in the DataBindings node in the designer.

It's expected that you'll wire up that attribute to something in your UserControl, like a textbox.